# SPF and Reply-To header

Tags: email, reply, spf

I found that SPF record are checked according to From sender's domain.
Is this supposed to be used also for Reply-To header or may I put in the Reply-To address what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it only checks the envelope sender. It's meant for *incoming* e-mails, so the receiving mail server might check whether the arriving e-mail message is sent from a server which is listed in the SPF record.

The `Reply-To` header is for different meanings. It will simply use that address as the one for answers, but it doesn't provide any information about the origin of the e-mail. Thus, only the envelope server is relevant here.

Comment: What is the envelope sender? When it is defined?

Comment: You have two sender addresses, `From:` and the envelope sender. The second is where delivery status should be sent, whereas the first one is where 'humans' respond. More on this here: https://www.pobox.com/helpspot/index.php?pg=kb.page&id=260

Comment: Nice, but by default is this the same as From? I'm working with a standard Exim server...

Comment: Usually they are the same, but they don't have to be (and that's what spammers take advantage of).